# Java run time environment mac

Tags: java, mac

I am trying to install an application on a MAC 10.6.4, however i get an installation error that no java runtime environment.

However on the java website, the mac section indicates that MAC provides its own java and should use the software update software to get the latest java application. I have done this and gotten the latest java however I still get the same error no java run time

is there something am missing?

Comment: I'm sensing that you might be trying to install OpenOffice? If that's the case, don't worry about it. The installer threw that error for me and it still works. I imagine it simply doesn't correctly detect the JRE. Also: migrate to Superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind is that this might search for an old JRE and doesn't work correctly with the JRE v6 installed on Snow Leopard.

Just to confirm that you have Java installed and working, you could try to start it, i.e. with the command  `java -version` in Terminal.app.

Comment: This is what i have as the version "java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03-307, mixed mode)"

Comment: So, Java is in fact installed and working. Do you see any hints re. the required Java version in the docs of the program in question?  Also, what is the program you try to install?